# Access to a php file in themes folder

Tags: php, wordpress, web

I am trying to access a php file in the theme folder of wordpress.

I have created a page call download.php. Users are redirected to this file after successful payment from paypal.

How can I access the file without using http://website.com/wp-content/themes/test/download.php. I want to access the file through http://website.com/download.php and would also like to know how I can use a function found in my functions.php in this file.

Pls help

I'm a lost.

Thanks

Comment: change the root of your project to  http://website.com/wp-content/themes/test in .htaccess file

Comment: test is the theme name. Everything is working fine on the site. I am simply unable to access a php file in the url. How to do this??

Comment: In your question you said you can access the file via /themes/test/download.php but not with website.com/download.php

Comment: Sorry guess I have not been able to explain myself well. so I want to access the file through http://website.com/download.php?

Comment: Can you access the file uding website.com/wp-content/themes/test/download.php?

Comment: do you provide any call back url when u return from paypal?

Comment: I generated the button on the paypal account itself. There have a paremeter 'return' and I have set the value to be 'website.com/download.php'.

Comment: wat error you get when you redirect from pay pal?

Comment: I am not having any error. Everything working find. Its just that instead of using the url  http://website.com/wp-content/themes/test/download.php to access the download.php file, I would like to use  http://website.com/download.php. I would like how to do that while keeping the download.php in my theme folder itself

Comment: ok then you need to use aliases in your apache server... have a look at this page http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html specially the mod_alias

Answer (score 0):

May be the answer can help someone.

To resolve the problem, I have created a page called 'Download' and in my page.php, I have checked if the title is 'Download', then I have included the file download.php in it.

Thanks for your help Umair Iqbal